# DB2 SQL : LISTAGG considering priority and deletion indicator

Tags: sql, db2

I have a dataset like below (the dataset is ordered by timestamp). In the below dataset for the combination of EMP_ID & DEPT_ID different courses can be assigned. We have to find out all courses valid for a date range for EMP_ID & DEPT_ID combination.

We have consider F_PRIORITY (first priority) and S_PRIORITY (second priority) attributes:

- "Critical > High > Medium > Low" valid for first priority.
- If for two records on same date (YYYYMMDD), if the F_PRIORITY value is same, then S_PRIORITY need to be considered. S_PRIORITY always have integer number and highest value gets the priority.
- If for any date (YYYYMMDD) we found both F_PRIORITY and S_PRIORITY are same then multiple course needs to be combined with comma separator.
- At any point if any course found as DELETED (DELETED=1) and if that course is considered based on priority value then that need to be deleted from the next effective start date.
- If a course is found for any date for a combination of EMP_ID and DEPT_ID with high priority then the same course should flow in all the next available dates. If same priority course found in next available date for the combination of EMP_ID and DEPT_ID then both the courses should be present with comma separated. If the priority of the course is higher in next available date then it will replace the previous date's course.

I want to calculate all these in DB2 database. If simple query can't help, then please let me know if any function can help.

Source Dataset:

```
D_DATE     EMP_ID  DEPT_ID  COURSE_ID F_PRIORITY  S_PRIORITY DELETED  D_TIMESTAMP
20190419   E1      D1       C1        Low         2          0        2019-04-19 12:10:18
20190521   E1      D1       C2        Medium      2          0        2019-05-21 12:10:18
20190521   E1      D1       C3        High        4          0        2019-05-21 14:10:18
20190521   E1      D1       C4        High        4          0        2019-05-21 14:11:18
20190621   E1      D1       C3        High        4          1        2019-06-21 15:10:18
20190621   E1      D1       C5        High        4          0        2019-06-21 16:10:18
20191021   E1      D1       C6        High        8          0        2019-06-21 16:10:18
20200121   E1      D1       C7        Critical    4          0        2019-05-21 14:10:18
20200121   E1      D1       C8        Critical    4          0        2019-05-21 14:11:18

20190419   E2      Null     C1        Low         2          0        2019-04-19 12:10:18
20190521   E2      Null     C2        Medium      2          0        2019-05-21 12:10:18
20190521   E2      Null     C3        High        4          0        2019-05-21 14:10:18
20190521   E2      Null     C4        High        4          0        2019-05-21 14:11:18
20190531   E2      Null     C2        Medium      2          1        2019-05-31 15:01:18

20190621   E2      D2       C3        High        4          0        2019-06-21 15:10:18
20190621   E2      D2       C5        High        6          0        2019-06-21 16:10:18
20190721   E2      D2       C5        High        6          1        2019-06-21 15:10:18
20191021   E2      D2       C7        Low         8          0        2019-06-21 16:10:18
```

Expected Output:

```
EMP_ID  DEPT_ID  COURSE_DTL  S_DATE      E_DATE
E1      D1       C1          20190419    20190520
E1      D1       C3,C4       20190521    20190620 (C2 not considered as Medium)
E1      D1       C4,C5       20190621    20191020 (C3 Deleted, so removed)
E1      D1       C6          20191021    20200120 (C6 takes priority as S_PRIORITY=8)
E1      D1       C7,C8       20200121    99991231 (C7, C8 F_PRIORITY=Critical; so takes priority)

E2      Null     C1          20190419    20190520
E2      Null     C3,C4       20190521    99991231 (addition of C2 does not impact as F_PRIORITY is less than C3 and C4. Also DELETED of C2 does not impact as C2 was not there in the consideration from Date=20190521)

E2      D2       C5          20190621    20190720
E2      D2       Null        20190721    20191020
E2      D2       C7          20191021    99991231
```

Comment: Why is `C4` included in the third group (`C4,C5`). Shouldn't it be `C5` only? Apart from that a single query can get this result relatively easy.

Comment: (C3,C4) was valid from 20190521 to 20190620 and only C3 was deleted on 20190621. So for date starting 20190621 it should be (C3,C4,C5) - (C3) i.e. (C4,C5). Also the priority are same. So we don't want to remove any course, if the next consecutive record's priority is same and not deleted

Comment: Strange explanation. There is no (20190621, E1, D1, C4) row, but you want C4 to appear in the (20190621, E1, D1) group. There is no such an appearance example in any other result row. You need to describe the rules for such a "row migration from another date". Why do we see (20190721, E2, D2, Null), but don't see (20190531, E2, Null, Null) in the result (the only row for given date and it's deleted)? What if for given date and IDs the only row with highest priority is deleted, but other rows exist? Do you want to get Null or list of non-deleted courses with next lower priority?

Comment: The rule is : 1. if a course is found for any date for a combination of EMP_ID and DEPT_ID with high priority then the same course should flow in all the next available dates. If same priority course found in next available date for the combination of EMP_ID and DEPT_ID then both the courses should be present with comma separated. if the priority of the course is higher in next available date then it will replace the previous date's course.

Comment: In the above example C4 wasn't there for 20190621, but was there for 20190521 and the priority (combining F_PRIORITY & S_PRIORITY) for C4 is same as C3; so for 20190621 as well C4 is there.

Comment: Why is for E2/D2 in expected output "Null" from 20190721 (and then C7), and not C3 all the time till 99991231? C5 was deleted at this point in time, so C3 is now the course with the highest priority... or the appearance of courses with higher priority means courses with lower priority get interrupted (deleted) automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given me an answer on higher priorities overriding validity of lower priorities, so I did both examples. In this first example, higher priority events "delete" lower priority events, consistent with Your expected output.

> ```
> WITH source (d_date, emp_id, dept_id, course_id, f_priority, s_priority, deleted, d_timestamp) AS
> ( VALUES ('20190419', 'E1', 'D1', 'C1', 'Low',      2, 0, '2019-04-19 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E1', 'D1', 'C2', 'Medium',   2, 0, '2019-05-21 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E1', 'D1', 'C3', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E1', 'D1', 'C4', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:11:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E1', 'D1', 'C3', 'High',     4, 1, '2019-06-21 15:10:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E1', 'D1', 'C5', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18'),
>          ('20191021', 'E1', 'D1', 'C6', 'High',     8, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18'),
>          ('20200121', 'E1', 'D1', 'C7', 'Critical', 4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:10:18'),
>          ('20200121', 'E1', 'D1', 'C8', 'Critical', 4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:11:18'),
>          ('20190419', 'E2', NULL, 'C1', 'Low',      2, 0, '2019-04-19 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E2', NULL, 'C2', 'Medium',   2, 0, '2019-05-21 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E2', NULL, 'C3', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E2', NULL, 'C4', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:11:18'),
>          ('20190531', 'E2', NULL, 'C2', 'Medium',   2, 1, '2019-05-31 15:01:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E2', 'D2', 'C3', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-06-21 15:10:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E2', 'D2', 'C5', 'High',     6, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18'),
>          ('20190721', 'E2', 'D2', 'C5', 'High',     6, 1, '2019-06-21 15:10:18'),
>          ('20191021', 'E2', 'D2', 'C7', 'Low',      8, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18')
> ), max_priorities (emp_id, dept_id, d_date, course_id, f_priority, s_priority, deleted, fs_ord_priority, max_fs_ord_priority) AS
> ( SELECT emp_id, dept_id, d_date, course_id, s.f_priority, s_priority, deleted, def.f_ord_priority*10+s_priority,
>          MAX(def.f_ord_priority*10+s_priority) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id, d_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
>     FROM source s
>       INNER JOIN (VALUES ('Low', 1), ('Medium', 2), ('High', 3), ('Critical', 4)) AS def(f_priority, f_ord_priority) ON s.f_priority = def.f_priority
> ), filtered_priorities (emp_id, dept_id, d_date, course_id, deleted, fs_ord_priority, entry_ord, entry_count, date_ord) AS
> ( SELECT emp_id, dept_id, d_date, course_id, deleted, fs_ord_priority,
>          ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id ORDER BY d_date, course_id),
>          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id),
>          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id ORDER BY d_date)
>     FROM max_priorities
>     WHERE max_fs_ord_priority = fs_ord_priority
> )
> , recursive_courses (emp_id, dept_id, d_date, course_dtl, current_fs_ord_priority, entry_ord, entry_count, date_ord) AS
> ( SELECT emp_id, dept_id, d_date, CAST(',' || course_id AS VARCHAR(100)), fs_ord_priority, entry_ord, entry_count, date_ord
>     FROM filtered_priorities
>     WHERE entry_ord = 1
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT n.emp_id, n.dept_id, n.d_date,
>          CASE WHEN o.current_fs_ord_priority < n.fs_ord_priority THEN ',' || n.course_id
>               WHEN o.current_fs_ord_priority > n.fs_ord_priority THEN o.course_dtl
>               WHEN o.current_fs_ord_priority = n.fs_ord_priority AND n.deleted = 0 THEN o.course_dtl || ',' || n.course_id
>               ELSE INSERT(o.course_dtl, LOCATE(','||n.course_id||',', o.course_dtl||','), LENGTH(','||n.course_id), '')
>          END,
>          CASE WHEN o.current_fs_ord_priority < n.fs_ord_priority THEN n.fs_ord_priority
>               WHEN o.current_fs_ord_priority = n.fs_ord_priority AND n.deleted = 1 AND LOCATE(',', o.course_dtl, 2) = 0 THEN -1
>               ELSE o.current_fs_ord_priority
>          END,
>          CASE WHEN o.current_fs_ord_priority > n.fs_ord_priority THEN -1 ELSE n.entry_ord END,
>          n.entry_count, n.date_ord
>     FROM recursive_courses o, filtered_priorities n
>     WHERE (o.emp_id, COALESCE(o.dept_id, 'N/A'), o.entry_ord + 1) = (n.emp_id, COALESCE(n.dept_id, 'N/A'), n.entry_ord)
>       AND n.entry_ord <= o.entry_count
> )
> SELECT emp_id, dept_id, CASE WHEN course_dtl != '' THEN SUBSTR(course_dtl, 2) END AS course_dtl,
>        d_date AS s_date,
>        COALESCE( INSERT(INSERT(CHAR(
>          DATE(INSERT(INSERT(LEAD(d_date) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id ORDER BY d_date), 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-')) - 1 DAY
>                  ), 5, 1, ''), 7, 1, '')
>                 , '99991231') AS e_date
>   FROM recursive_courses
>   WHERE entry_ord = date_ord
>   ORDER BY emp_id, COALESCE(dept_id, ''), d_date
> ;
> ```

> ```
> EMP_ID | DEPT_ID | COURSE_DTL |   S_DATE |   E_DATE
> -----: | ------: | ---------: | -------: | -------:
>     E1 |      D1 |         C1 | 20190419 | 20190520
>     E1 |      D1 |      C3,C4 | 20190521 | 20190620
>     E1 |      D1 |      C4,C5 | 20190621 | 20191020
>     E1 |      D1 |         C6 | 20191021 | 20200120
>     E1 |      D1 |      C7,C8 | 20200121 | 99991231
>     E2 |    null |         C1 | 20190419 | 20190520
>     E2 |    null |      C3,C4 | 20190521 | 99991231
>     E2 |      D2 |         C5 | 20190621 | 20190720
>     E2 |      D2 |       null | 20190721 | 20191020
>     E2 |      D2 |         C7 | 20191021 | 99991231
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=ed2d233869c60d8f9fc65d9676dcc7b6)*

But I had to do a recursive CTE.
Commentary to individual CTEs:

- max_priorities: find the maximum priority in a day (per emp_id and dept_id) as a numerical value (f_priority and s_priority combined); "Delete" rows with lower priority don't have to be considered, as higher priority takes precedence,
- filtered_priorities: take only the highest priority per day (and emp_id and dept_id, of course...), calculate entry order, entry/date order and count (so as to identify the last entry in a day and the last entry per emp_id and dept_id),
- recursive_courses: take one row at a time by their order, according to priority values, deletes etc. calculate its courses (always with a leading comma for practical reasons!; if we came upon a removal of the last active course, priority drops to -1,
- last INSERTS are there just to convert the next d_date (YYYYMMDD) into a real DATE, find the previous day and convert it back to YYYYMMDD.

With the second alternative, if all courses have to be explicitly deleted to mark an end, I chose a different approach: I tried to find out for each and every day, which courses are valid. I won't comment it further, as I am not sure, if You are interested in this answer too. (It differs from Your "expected output".)

> ```
> WITH source (d_date, emp_id, dept_id, course_id, f_priority, s_priority, deleted, d_timestamp) AS
> ( VALUES ('20190419', 'E1', 'D1', 'C1', 'Low',      2, 0, '2019-04-19 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E1', 'D1', 'C2', 'Medium',   2, 0, '2019-05-21 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E1', 'D1', 'C3', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E1', 'D1', 'C4', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:11:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E1', 'D1', 'C3', 'High',     4, 1, '2019-06-21 15:10:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E1', 'D1', 'C5', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18'),
>          ('20191021', 'E1', 'D1', 'C6', 'High',     8, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18'),
>          ('20200121', 'E1', 'D1', 'C7', 'Critical', 4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:10:18'),
>          ('20200121', 'E1', 'D1', 'C8', 'Critical', 4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:11:18'),
>          ('20190419', 'E2', NULL, 'C1', 'Low',      2, 0, '2019-04-19 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E2', NULL, 'C2', 'Medium',   2, 0, '2019-05-21 12:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E2', NULL, 'C3', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:10:18'),
>          ('20190521', 'E2', NULL, 'C4', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-05-21 14:11:18'),
>          ('20190531', 'E2', NULL, 'C2', 'Medium',   2, 1, '2019-05-31 15:01:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E2', 'D2', 'C3', 'High',     4, 0, '2019-06-21 15:10:18'),
>          ('20190621', 'E2', 'D2', 'C5', 'High',     6, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18'),
>          ('20190721', 'E2', 'D2', 'C5', 'High',     6, 1, '2019-06-21 15:10:18'),
>          ('20191021', 'E2', 'D2', 'C7', 'Low',      8, 0, '2019-06-21 16:10:18')
> ), all_dates (d_date) AS
> ( SELECT INSERT(INSERT(CHAR(min_dt+(a+b+c)  DAYS),5,1,''),7,1,'')
>     FROM ( SELECT DATE(INSERT(INSERT(MIN(d_date),5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')), DATE(INSERT(INSERT(MAX(d_date),5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')) FROM SOURCE ) AS def(min_dt, max_dt)
>       CROSS JOIN (VALUES 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) AS aa(a)
>       CROSS JOIN (VALUES 00,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90) AS bb(b)
>       CROSS JOIN (VALUES 000,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900) AS cc(c)
>     WHERE min_dt + (a+b+c) DAYS <= max_dt
>   UNION ALL
>   VALUES '99991231'
> ), all_dates_and_emp_dept_courses (emp_id, dept_id, course_id, d_date, f_priority, s_priority) AS
> ( SELECT def.emp_id, def.dept_id, def.course_id, d.d_date,
>          NULLIF(LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN s.deleted=1 THEN 'DELETED' ELSE s.f_priority END, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY def.emp_id, def.dept_id, def.course_id ORDER BY d.d_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 'DELETED'),
>          NULLIF(LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN s.deleted=1 THEN -100 ELSE s.s_priority END, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY def.emp_id, def.dept_id, def.course_id ORDER BY d.d_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), -100)
>     FROM (SELECT emp_id, dept_id, course_id,
>                  MIN(MIN(d_date))OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
>                  MAX(MAX(d_date))OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
>             FROM source
>             GROUP BY emp_id, dept_id, course_id
>          ) AS def (emp_id, dept_id, course_id, min_d_date, max_d_date)
>       INNER JOIN all_dates d ON d.d_date BETWEEN def.min_d_date AND def.max_d_date OR d.d_date = '99991231'
>       LEFT JOIN source s ON (def.emp_id, COALESCE(def.dept_id,'N/A'), def.course_id, d.d_date) = (s.emp_id, COALESCE(s.dept_id,'N/A'), s.course_id, s.d_date)
> ), all_dates_and_emp_dept_priorities (emp_id, dept_id, d_date, f_priority, s_priority, max_fs_priority, course_dtl, count_changes) AS
> ( SELECT emp_id, dept_id, d_date,
>          f_priority, s_priority, LAST_VALUE(f_priority||'/'||CHAR(s_priority)) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id, d_date ORDER BY DECODE(f_priority, 'Low', 1, 'Medium', 2, 'High', 3, 'Critical', 4) NULLS FIRST, s_priority NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
>          LISTAGG(course_id, ','),
>          SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(LAG(LISTAGG(course_id, ',')) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id, f_priority, s_priority ORDER BY d_date),'N/A')=COALESCE(LISTAGG(course_id, ','),'N/A') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id, f_priority, s_priority ORDER BY d_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
>     FROM all_dates_and_emp_dept_courses
>     GROUP BY emp_id, dept_id, d_date, f_priority, s_priority
> )
> SELECT DISTINCT emp_id, dept_id, course_dtl,
>        MIN(d_date) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id, course_dtl ORDER BY count_changes RANGE BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING),
>        MAX(d_date) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id, dept_id, course_dtl ORDER BY count_changes RANGE BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING)
>   FROM all_dates_and_emp_dept_priorities
>   WHERE COALESCE(f_priority||'/'||CHAR(s_priority),'N/A')=COALESCE(max_fs_priority,'N/A')
> ORDER BY emp_id, dept_id, 4
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> EMP_ID | DEPT_ID | COURSE_DTL |        4 |        5
> -----: | ------: | ---------: | -------: | -------:
>     E1 |      D1 |         C1 | 20190419 | 20190520
>     E1 |      D1 |      C3,C4 | 20190521 | 20190620
>     E1 |      D1 |      C4,C5 | 20190621 | 20191020
>     E1 |      D1 |         C6 | 20191021 | 20200120
>     E1 |      D1 |      C7,C8 | 20200121 | 99991231
>     E2 |      D2 |         C5 | 20190621 | 20190720
>     E2 |      D2 |         C3 | 20190721 | 99991231
>     E2 |    null |         C1 | 20190419 | 20190520
>     E2 |    null |      C3,C4 | 20190521 | 99991231
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3677c3394006d366692b320cb2d1b410)*

Comment: It seems like the solution going in a infinite loop. The actual table is having 500K rows andthe query is running foe ever

Comment: Which of the both? The first or the second? Only the first has a recursive CTE, but a finite one. Can You test the data with the second solution (even if output would differ to expected output)? Can You perhaps try it with less input data? What is the performance (especially RAM) of the DB machine?